# Making a Responsive Styled Component DRYer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components, react-props, react-component

I have the following code to help me with responsive design in `Styled Components`:

```
const breakpoints = {
  tablet: "769px",
  desktop: "1024px",
  widescreen: "1216px",
  fullhd: "1408px"
};

const gridCSS = ({ bg, color }) => css`
  background-color: ${bg};
  color: ${color};
`;

const responsiveGrid = (key, prop) =>
  prop &&
  css`
    @media screen and (min-width: ${breakpoints[key]}) {
      color: ${prop.color};
      background-color: ${prop.bg};
    }
  `;

const Grid = styled.div(
  ({ color, bg, desktop, tablet }) => css`
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  ${responsiveGrid("tablet", tablet)}
  ${responsiveGrid("desktop", desktop)}
  ${gridCSS}
`
);

function App() {
  return (
    <Grid
      color="orange"
      bg="lightgreen"
      tablet={{
        color: "green",
        bg: "orange"
      }}
      desktop={{
        color: "yellow",
        bg: "purple"
      }}
    >
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      </div>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

Now this works as I want it to.  The text and background colors change depending on the screen size.

However, I would like to note a certain repetitiveness in the code:

For instance, the `gridCSS` function contains exactly the same css properties and prop names as the `responsiveGrid` function.  Both of them have a `color` and `background-color` property and both of them reference a a `color` and `bg` prop.

But, if I try to inject `gridCSS` into `responsiveGrid it does not work.
  In other words, this works:

```
const responsiveGrid = (key, {bg, color}) =>
  (color || bg) &&
  css`
    @media screen and (min-width: ${breakpoints[key]}) {
      color: ${color};
      background-color: ${bg};
    }
  `;
```

But this does **not** work:

```
const responsiveGrid = (key, {bg, color}) =>
  (color || bg) &&
  css`
    @media screen and (min-width: ${breakpoints[key]}) {
      ${gridCSS}
    }
  `;
```

So, what I want to know is whether or not there is a way to have one central location for the css property names and their corresponding props without having to write it twice (once within the `gridCSS` function and a second time within the `responsiveGrid` function.

Note, the end result that I am looking for is the following:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Grid
      color="orange"
      bg="lightgreen"
      tablet={{
        color: "green",
        bg: "orange"
      }}
      desktop={{
        color: "yellow",
        bg: "purple"
      }}
    >
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      </div>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

Whereby I can set a `color` or `bg` prop without any media queries as well as set the **same** props within a media query prop like `tablet` or `desktop`.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

P.S.  In case it is helpful, here is the codesandbox for the above code:  https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-brook-ughkv?fontsize=14

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution that I came up with:

```
const breakpoints = {
  tablet: {
    value: 769,
    unit: "px"
  },
  desktop: {
    value: 1024,
    unit: "px"
  },
  widescreen: {
    value: 1216,
    unit: "px"
  },
  fullhd: {
    value: 1408,
    unit: "px"
  }
};

const breakpointKeys = Object.keys(breakpoints);

const gridCSS = ({ bg, textColor, ...props }) => {
  let mediaQueryCSS = breakpointKeys.map(key => {
    let mediaQuery = breakpoints[key].value + breakpoints[key].unit;
    let newMQ = mediaQuery - 1
    console.log(newMQ)

    return css`
      @media screen and (min-width: ${mediaQuery}) {
        color: ${props[key] && props[key].textColor};
        background-color: ${props[key] && props[key].bg};
      }
    `;
  });

  return css`
    background-color: ${bg};
    color: ${textColor};
    ${mediaQueryCSS};
  `;
};

const Grid = styled.div(
  ({ color, bg, desktop, tablet }) => css`
    display: grid;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    ${gridCSS}
  `
);

function App() {
  return (
    <Grid
      textColor="orange"
      bg="lightgreen"
      tablet={{
        textColor: "green",
        bg: "orange"
      }}
      desktop={{
        textColor: "yellow",
        bg: "purple"
      }}
    >
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      </div>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```